# Propagation of exceptions in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

does Spring Boot wraps/hides/encapsulates exceptions one way or another ?

I get some strange behaviour when an exception is produced.
For instance, in a Spring Boot + JPA project, if i comment out the @Entity annotation :

```
@Table(name = "XXX")
//@Entity
public class Contract
{
...
}
```

i get the following exception (warning) :

```
2018-12-10 19:09:33.153 DEBUG DESKTOP-48HHHCD --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.c.CollectionSecondPass               : Second pass for collection: cp.dmo.bean.ContribuablePar.listeContratMensu
2018-12-10 19:09:33.153 DEBUG DESKTOP-48HHHCD --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.c.a.CollectionBinder                 : Binding a collection of element: cp.dmo.bean.ContribuablePar.listeContratMensu
2018-12-10 19:09:33.154  WARN DESKTOP-48HHHCD --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testpopulationserviceso' defined in file [C:\Users\celfer\AppData\Local\Temp\1-dmo\WEB-INF\classes\conf\application\applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'testpopulationserviceimpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testpopulationserviceimpl' defined in file [C:\Users\celfer\AppData\Local\Temp\1-dmo\WEB-INF\classes\conf\application\applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'testpopulationdao' while setting bean property 'testpopulationdao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testpopulationdao' defined in file [C:\Users\celfer\AppData\Local\Temp\1-dmo\WEB-INF\classes\conf\application\applicationContext-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/celfer/AppData/Local/Temp/1-dmo/WEB-INF/lib/lombok-jpa-24.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/conf/applicationContext-datasources-jpa2.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManager' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/celfer/AppData/Local/Temp/1-dmo/WEB-INF/lib/lombok-jpa-24.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/conf/applicationContext-datasources-jpa2.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2018-12-10 19:09:33.155 DEBUG DESKTOP-48HHHCD --- [ost-  startStop-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'lecturepersonneso'
```

So the exception says the application is unable to build a Hibernate SessionFactory but it does not point out precisely where the problem comes from.

Any clue ?
Thanks

Comment: there are dependancy exception, please share your code that we can easily track it.

Comment: Well, it does tell you where the problem comes from: it can't build the Hibernate Session as your bean is missing: Error creating bean with name 'testpopulationdao'.

Comment: You say "Spring Boot", but it looks like you're doing a lot of configuration by hand (and using legacy XML) instead of letting Boot take care of it. Most likely, there's a problem with scanning for persistable entity classes. Post the entire stack trace *and your XML configuration*.

Comment: @AlexB The error is probably coming out of Hibernate itself, when it can't find any entity classes at all, but there's not enough information to say for certain.

Comment: Agree with advice given by @chrylis

Comment: Can you post pom.xml.. at high level, looks like dependencies are NOT sufficient. **Error creating bean with name 'entityManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/celfer/AppData/Local/Temp/1-dmo/WEB-INF/lib/lombok-jpa-24.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar!/conf/applicationContext-datasources-jpa2.xml]:**

Comment: Thanks for helping. However the question is not where is the problem (the annotation @Entity is missing), the question is why Spring is not showing more information about the Hibernate/JPA exception. Most of the time when there is a mapping error, we get a BeanCreationException with very little more information. It takes hours to find out where the error exactly is because Spring instantiates the Hibernate components.

Comment: Spring instantiates the Hibernate components and catches any Hibernate exception and rethrows it as a bean creation exception, while hiding the real cause. How can i log the real cause of the exception ?

Comment: The cause is in the exception, Spring doesn't hide anything. If there is no information in there then there is no more information. You can try running with `--debug` to get some more information but the real problem is the fact that hibernate produces no more information. There is nothing Spring can do about that.